# A more succinct way to transform JS object?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Please see code below.  Is there a more succinct way to transform the `originalObject` into `myObject`?
The key is that I'm trying to set `myObject`'s property names based on the `id` within each property in `originalObject`.

```
myObject = Object
    .values( originalObject )
    .reduce( (acc, x) => {
        let propHolder = {}
        propHolder[x.id] = false
        return Object.assign( acc, propHolder )
    }, {} )
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for `originalObject` and `myObject`?

Comment: How about just `acc[x.id] = false; return acc;`? No need to involve a "propHolder".

Comment: Why are you using a plain object with data-driven keys? Why not use `Map`?

Comment: @naomik Using a `Map` is an interesting idea that has conceptual attractiveness, but it will not integrate as simply/readably with my front-end framework's components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Javascript's `spread` syntax:

```
const myObject = Object
  .values(originalObject)
  .reduce((acc, x) => ({ ...acc, [x.id]: false }), {})
```

More reading: [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Do note that this is part of the ES2018 specification.

Comment: Thanks Jaye.  I felt this answer had the most succinct code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `let`, you have computed properties:

```
myObject = Object.values(originalObject).reduce((acc, x)=>{
             return Object.assign(acc, {[x.id]: false})
           },{})
```

Now since the arrow function is just a return:

```
myObject =
  Object.values(originalObject)
    .reduce((acc, x) => Object.assign(acc, {[x.id]: false}), {})
```

and if you don’t mind making an array:

```
myObject =
  Object.values(originalObject)
    .map(x => ({[x.id]: false}))
    .reduce(Object.assign, {});
```

I would prefer to have a `fromPairs` function on hand, though.

```
myObject = fromPairs(
  Object.values(originalObject)
    .map(x => [x.id, false])
);
```

If you use Lodash’s `fromPairs`, you can also use its `map`.

```
myObject = _.fromPairs(
  _.map(originalObject, x => [x.id, false])
);
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  This answer was a vast improvement over my own original code and I appreciate your detail.

Answer (score 2):

See Ryan’s answer for elegant but long one-liners. But since you were asking for a succinct way, here's the simple solution:

```
myObject = {};
for (const k in originalObject)
   myObject[originalObject[k].id] = false;
```

Or possibly more interesting:

```
myObject = {};
for (const {id} of Object.values(originalObject))
   myObject[id] = false;
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi.  This is also a helpful answer.